# How to get exact character from a byte

Tags: c#

How i write 'non supported chars' and convert it into byte without '????'. When i receive byte and convert it into file i get a half of the full file with many '????'.

Without byte converter

```
ÿØÿá "Exif  MM *               ÿí 8Photoshop 3.0 8BIM      8BIM%     ÔŒÙ 
²é€ ˜ìøB~ÿÀ «à ÿÄ               

ÿÄ µ   } !1AQa "q2‘¡#B±ÁRÑð$3br‚    
%&'()*456789:CDEFGHIJSTUVWXYZcdefghijstuvwxyzƒ„…†‡ˆ‰Š’“”•–—˜™š¢£¤¥¦§¨©ª²³ 
´µ¶·¸¹ºÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊÒÓÔÕÖ×ØÙÚáâãäåæçèéêñòóôõö÷øùúÿÄ             

ÿÄ µ   w !1AQ aq"2B‘¡±Á #3RðbrÑ
$4á%ñ&'()*56789:CDEFGHIJSTUVWXYZcdefghijstuvwxyz
```

---

And with byte converter

```
?????"Exif??MM?*??????????????????8Photoshop 3.0?8BIM?????? 
8BIM%?????????????  ???B~???????????????????    
???????}?!1AQa"q2???#B??R??$3br? %&'()*456789:CDEFGHIJSTUVWXYZcdefghijstuvwxyz?????????????????????????????????????????? 
?????????????????????????????????????????   
??????w?!1AQaq"2?B????  #3R?br?
$4?%?&'()*56789:CDEFGHIJSTUVWXYZcdefghijstuvwxyz
```

Comment: How you have done it? Then we might tell you why you get what you get.

Comment: And by the way there is no exact character for a byte. It depends on the definition(the encoding).

Comment: Can you share more about what are you trying to do here. It's not clear. The first string you share looks like the ascii representation of a file with the ascii characters that represent the byte in that position. Instead of that, what would you prefer? It's not clear. A byte is a byte is a byte. It can be represented as ascii, decimal, octal, hex, binary, utf-8, etc, etc, etc, etc, etc, etc. How do you want these bytes represented?

Comment: I transform a png file into byte and decode it with `Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer, 0, bytesRead);` The first is the original file the second the converted file

Comment: JNevill I want to encode a PNG file in byte and get the same output as the file i converted.

Comment: Decoding arbitrary data as ascii is a terrible idea. If you want to represent binary data as text, use something like base64 encoding. If you want to extract textual data from headers, use some suitable library that can correctly read the header data.

Comment: ASCII is a 7-bit encoding so don't represent any possible byte. Why do you want your picture as text presentation? Why do you think there is something to convert? Convert for what?

Comment: You want bytes. Then why you using `GetString` method?

Comment: `var bytes = File.ReadAllBytes("file.png");` `File.WriteAllBytes("file.png", bytes);`

Comment: A (PNG) file is already stored as bytes. Why the need to convert it to text/string?

Comment: [Convert.ToBase64String()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.tobase64string?view=net-6.0) is meant to encode any binary data into a string. There is also a FromBase64String to revert it

Comment: I think you recently asked a similar question (apparently deleted). It was shown how to write an image to a MemoryStream, and then receive an array of bytes.

Comment: Alexander Petrov Yeah i'm trying to do a socket and transfert png client to server that's why. I keep try find the solution but nothing for now